# Compare Two Columns with Complex Conditionals

Tags: excel

I can't get my head wrapped around this multi conditional between two columns. I have two columns A and B but would like to use some formulas to compare each "grouping" of column A. For example in Column A, if all "group 2" has all Column B values as Pass, it is a pass.

Edit: I've updated it with some more rules since this just a bit more complicated for me to wrap my head around.

There are only 5 criteria:

- PASS, PROG, UNAVAIL, IGNORE, "BLANK"

Rules:

1. FAIL if subgroup has 1 or more fail
2. IGNORE if subgroup has 1 or more ignore
3. PASS if ALL PASS or combination of PASS and UNAVAIL
4. PROG if NOT fail and a combination of PASS, UNAVAIL, PROG
5. "BLANK"s are treated as UNAVAIL

[image]

Appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: Your conditions don't seem to exhaust all possibilities -- what if a group has a combination of pass and uncertain? By your criteria the group is neither a pass nor a fail nor uncertain.

Comment: Also there is an ambiguous test, `In the case of Column A "Group 2", if it contains at least 1 pass, it is a pass, however if there is at least 1 fail the whole thing is a fail` so what happens if there is 1 pass 1 fail?

Comment: Are there only these 5 groups in column A?  Can the solution incorporate a reference list of distinct groups?

Comment: That's correct John and Dan. I understand that it doesn't exhaust all possible combinations. This is partly because I'd like to learn and in order to prove my understanding, do it for all cases myself. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answer changed to reflect new criteria)

This sheet:

[image]

Was created with the following two formulas (using named ranges in A-C where the name is in the first row):

In C1 I entered (then copied)

```
=CONCATENATE(TRIM(A2),"-", IF(LEN(TRIM(B2)) > 0, TRIM(B2), "UNAVAIL"))
```

In F2 I entered (then copied)

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Tag, E2 &"-FAIL") >0, "FAIL",IF(COUNTIF(Tag, E2 &"-IGNORE") >0,"IGNORE",IF(COUNTIF(Group,E2) = COUNTIF(Tag, E2 &"-PASS") + COUNTIF(Tag, E2 &"-UNAVAIL"),"PASS","PROG")))
```

The 4th case is like an else at the bottom of a switch -- no need to explicitly check the condition.

Comment: Hi John, I've tried your method but had a difficult time what was going on at the end of your formula where you have the "= COUNTIF(Group,E2),"Uncertain","Pass"))" I'm not sure if your formula can be adapted for the new rules I edited above, but I do appreciate any feedback!

Comment: E2 holds the value "1" (E2 is updated as the formula is dragged to E3 etc.). The formula counts the number of tags that look like "1-Uncertain" and compares this count to the number of 1s in column A. If these 2 numbers agree then all 1's are uncertain and "uncertain" is returned otherwise (since the case of even a single failure has already been accounted for) 1's would be a collection of uncertain and pass which I decided to score as "pass" since your original post was ambiguous. This sort of approach should still work with your new rules, albeit at the cost of a more involved nested-if.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you. Going through a bunch of nested IFs gets a bit confusing. I just have one last question and I think I can set this up on my own, but if you look at Rule #4 "PROG if NOT fail and a combination of PASS, UNAVAIL, PROG", how would I go about comparing three results instead of two (like you explained in the last comment?)

Comment: I'll play around with it but I THINK I can concatenate a similar if statement in the end since all the beginning ifs take care of the other results. I'll double check for your response in a bit. Thank you sooo much!

Comment: If Rule #4 is the logical complement of rules 1-3 then no need to check explicitly. See if my new answer helps.

Comment: Yes, I got it working! Except its a tad bit longer than yours but works similarly. In your formula, you have the word "Tag", how do I use the header name or do I have to explicitly write the range A2:A9999999(some absurd number) to get every entry in tag?

Comment: Highlight your data in columns A - C (or even the whole columns if you want it to grow) and, on the formula tab, in the Name part of the ribbon, select the option "Create from selection" a dialog box will pop-up -- select the "names in top row" option (but not the left column option -- deselect that). This will create the names "Group" and "Tag" (as well as "Result" -- which isn't actually used but it can't hurt to have it around, you might need it later).

Answer (score 0):

along the same lines, 
add a column C, where if the result is pass value is 0,
result is fail value will be -100000 or so (large negative)
for uncertain use some prime negative like -3/
then use a pivot table and use the sum of the values 
Then you can use formulas to deduce different conditions.

the use of large negative number is to be be able to if all the results 
are uncertain, as long as they don't overlap the range less than -100000 or so.
anyway you get the idea.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This formula may work (enter as an array formula CTRL-ENTER):

```
=IF(SUM(IF(IF($A$2:$A$23=$E2,$B$2:$B$23,"OUT_OF_GROUP")="FAIL",1,0))>0,"FAIL",IF(SUM(IF(IF($A$2:$A$23=$E2,$B$2:$B$23,"OUT_OF_GROUP")="IGNORE",1,0))>0,"IGNORE",IF(SUM(IF(IF($A$2:$A$23=$E2,$B$2:$B$23,"OUT_OF_GROUP")="PASS",1,0))+SUM(IF(IF($A$2:$A$23=$E2,$B$2:$B$23,"OUT_OF_GROUP")="UNAVAIL",1,0))+SUM(IF(IF($A$2:$A$23=$E2,$B$2:$B$23,"OUT_OF_GROUP")=0,1,0))=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$23=$E2,1,0)),"PASS","PROG")))
```

Here Group and Result are in $A$2:$A$23 and $B$2:$B$23, respectively. E2:E11 holds "s1" through "s10". I assumed Rule 3 meant that a combination of UNAVAIL and blanks is a PASS --- the logic could be modified to make that a PROG.